# Error 403 when download image in web page

Tags: java, url, connection, user-agent

I am looking to make a program that downloads all images of a web page, but when I launch the program, I've a 403 error.

I tried to add a user-agent as I read it on the Internet, but it did not fix the problem.

```
URL url2 = new URL(m.group().substring(2));
URLConnection uc = url2.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64;rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0");
uc.connect();
Files.copy(uc.getInputStream(),  Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Oromis\\Downloads\\Textures\\New\\" + ++i + ".png"));
```

I would like the images to save themselves in a directory, but actually, I've this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://d1u5p3l4wpay3k.cloudfront.net/minecraft_fr_gamepedia/thumb/5/5c/B%C3%BBche_de_ch%C3%AAne_TU.png/160px-B%C3%BBche_de_ch%C3%AAne_TU.png?version=54ead9ac1cdc9f7287b4c4575183abea 2x
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at Test.main(Test.java:31)
```

Comment: For the same code, I can get the image without any issue. what is in `m.group().substring(2)`?

Comment: Because I have ", " before my URL, it's these two characters that allow me to get the URLs by the Parser

Comment: For you, it's work with the same URL?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: Weird, however URL is valid, I can access it by my browser :/

Comment: Just wrap the code in a main method block and put your url instead of `m.group().substring(2)`. it should return the image.

Comment: Same error for me :/

Comment: may be your firewall block the request.

Comment: Hum... Maybe... Do you know how I can authorize this?